# How to count number of Cases in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, conditional-statements

How can one find number of Cases in SQL? For example, following code has 5 Case statements

```
Select
up.user_id,
(
    case when up.email is null then 0 else 1 end
    +
    case when up.bio is null then 0 else 1 end
    +
    case when up.website is null then 0 else 1 end
    +
    case when up.location is null then 0 else 1 end
    +
    case when up.name is null then 0 else 1 end
) * 100 / **5** as complete
from users_profiles up
```

I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: You can not use any DBMS to do that. PostgreSQL can _execute_ a SQL statement, not do _lexical analysis_ on it for anything other than parsing the statement into a plan for execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a function with variable number of arguments, e.g.:

```
create or replace function not_null_ratio(variadic args text[])
returns numeric language plpgsql as $$
declare
    res numeric = 0;
begin
    for i in 1..array_length(args, 1) 
    loop
        res := res+ (args[i] is not null)::integer;
    end loop;
    return res * 100 / array_length(args, 1);
end $$;

select not_null_ratio('a', 'b', null, 'd');

   not_null_ratio    
---------------------
 75.0000000000000000
(1 row)
```

In your query:

```
select
    up.user_id,
    not_null_ratio(up.email, up.bio, up.website, up.location, up.name) as complete
from users_profiles up
```

---

SQL functions can also have variable number of arguments. This variant may be a bit faster:

```
create or replace function not_null_ratio_sql(variadic args text[])
returns numeric language sql as $$
    select count(elem) * 100.0 / count(*)
    from unnest(args) elem
$$;

select not_null_ratio_sql('a', 'b', null);

 not_null_ratio_sql  
---------------------
 66.6666666666666667
(1 row)
```

Comment: Worked like a Charm. Thanks